# Range-based loop use another operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a prime generator based on what I've seen in python by Sieve of Eratosthenes so this generator basically generate prime numbers with good performances.

What I would want is to use the range based loop on a range of prime number so here is what I did :

```
//Consider prime_generator a class with both operator*, operator!= and operator< overloaded

class primes_range {
private:
    unsigned int max;
public:
    primes_range(unsigned int max) : max(max) {}
    prime_generator begin() const {
        return prime_generator(); //so this generator begin from 2 to
                                  //infinity and beyond but of course
                                  //all primes
    }
    prime_generator end() const {
         prime_generator result;
         for (:*result < max; ++result) {} //so this thing actually create a 
                                           //generator and increment it until it
                                           //gives the first prime number 
                                           //above max so it basically do
                                           //all the work that I don't
                                           //want it to do now
         return rest;
    }
};
```

So in my main, I would want to use the range-based loop, that's the point of the primes_range class.

```
int main() {
    for (auto && i : primes_range(10)) { //So here, this is silly because
                                         //the range-based loop will use end()
                                         //wich will calculate all the prime
                                         //numbers at the very beginning
                                         //and i will increment apart from
                                         //this starting process
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course instead I could use a simple loop :

```
int main() {
    for (prime_generator pg; *pg < 10; ++pg) {
        cout << *pg << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But because the range-base loop is easier to read and prevent to use the operator*, I would want to use it instead, so my question is : Is there a way to make the range-base loop use another operator than != (in this case <) ? Maybe overloard a particular function for primes_range or specialize a comparator ?

Comment: No. The meaning of the range-based loop is defined as it is, and it is not customizable. The only customization points are the begin and end values.

Comment: You need to redesign your `primes_range`. Instead of returning a `prime_generator`, it should return a wrapper.

Comment: What would it change T.C. ?

Comment: You could implement a correct `operator!=` so it can be compared with `end()`.

Comment: @rubenvb What do you mean ? You suggest to implement the operator!= in prime_generator so when I compare 10 and 11 it gives me false ? Or the same thing but wrapped as T.C. said ?
If it's the case, it would be difficult as it's not possible to say if an int n is prime without looping the previous prime numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).

Comment: @Steranoid You're giving it an iterator interface (partially). Better of course would be do write it as a proper iterator, but if operator!= is what you need, you can write it so it does what the for loop expects. I never said it was a great idea. But it should work if done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing the whole work on the `end()` method your iterator must generate the next prime number at each call to `operator++` and then returning them in the calls to `operator*`. So the scheme for your iterator class may be:

```
class prime_generator {
   typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
   int cur;
   prime_generator& operator++() {
      cur = GenerateNextPrime();
      return *this;
   }
   int operator*() {
      return curr;
   }
};
```

NOTES:

- For the range-based for to work you need at least `operator++` and `operator*` on your iterator class, with the signatures above.
- The `forward_iterator_tag` declared in the iterator class tell what kind of iterator you are creating. In this case a forward iterator is one that suport the "get next" operation via `operator++` but not random access via indexing for example. It is a good practice to declare this category field in iterator classes in order to hint the standard library methods about the best algorithms to use with your iterators.

Comment: It's already like that, what I said about the end method doing all the work is that the end() method will increment a prime_generator to get the final prime number (for example, if, I use primes_range(10).end(), it will create a generator at 2 and then increment it to 3, 5, 7 and finally 11 and return 11), so if I use the range-based loop on it, it will use the same loop two times.

Comment: I don't quite remember how the sieve works but I suppose it must start from 0 or 1 to generate the primes, Am I correct?If this is the case You must create an iterator with `curr = 1` in the `begin()` method and an invalid iterator just for comparison in the `end()` method, since you can not just generate the last prime right away. I think I will write one more answer with a complete example.

Comment: No it begins from 2; 1 is not prime nor 0.

Comment: @Steranoid: You may do as some iterator with *invalid* state which represent the end. so the check to pass in *invalid* state is done is `operator ++`

Comment: `++` can return `void` for a range-based for loop (the return value is not used).  This may not be wise.

Comment: Yes, it can. Depends  on what you are implementing, here it seems to be harmless to return a valid iterator (or reference)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example on iterators. I forgot to mention above the you need `operator!=` for the `range based for` to work because it must compare the current iterator to the result of the `end()` method. In the code below you just have to place the correct implementation of your algorithm in the `generate_next_prime` function, or place it inside the casses as you wish.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int generate_next_prime(int previous) {
    // TODO: a correct one!
    return previous + 1;
}

class prime_generator {
    int limit;

public:

    prime_generator(int limit)
        : limit(limit) {}

    class iterator {
        int cur, limit;

    public:

        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

        iterator(int cur, int limit)
            : cur(cur), limit(limit) {}

        iterator& operator++() {
            cur = generate_next_prime(cur);
            return *this;
        }   

        bool operator==(const iterator &other) {
            // NOTE: for the primes application maybe you should
            // use >= instead of == to ensure cur will not pass limit
            // silently, or do something more elaborate
            return cur == other.cur &&
                   limit == other.limit;
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator &other) {
            return !(*this == other);
        }   

        int operator*() {
            return cur;
        }   
    };  

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(2, limit);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(limit, limit);
    }
};

int main() {
    for (auto p : prime_generator(5))
        std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to cap `cur` with `limit`. (as `cur` might jump over limit with prime).

Comment: **Edit** you previous **answer**. Not two answer for 1 question!!! and delete one of them

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you told me, I come here with a solution, this is basically an adapter.

```
class primes_range {
private:
    unsigned int max;

    class limited_prime_generator {
    private:
        prime_generator pg;
        unsigned int limit;
        bool reachedLimit;

    public:
        limited_prime_generator(unsigned int limit, bool reachedLimit = false) : pg(), limit(limit), reachedLimit(reachedLimit) {}

        limited_prime_generator & operator++() {
            if (not reachedLimit) {
                reachedLimit = *(++pg) >= limit;
            }

            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(limited_prime_generator const & lpg) const {
            return operator*() != *lpg;
        }
        unsigned int operator*() const {
            if (reachedLimit)
                return limit;
            else
                return *pg;
        }
    };

public:
    primes_range(unsigned int max) : max(max) {}

    limited_prime_generator begin() const {
        return limited_prime_generator(max);
    }

    limited_prime_generator end() const {
        return limited_prime_generator(max, true);
    }
};
```